# How do you use pictures and memes in your posts appropriately?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes people like to use big, eye-catching pictures or memes in their posts to help illustrate what they're saying. Some examples (full disclosure, the first two are mine):

1. [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252234/456814).
2. [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23415303/3).
3. [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/456814).
4. [What's the difference between git reflog and log?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17859891/456814).

Obviously big pictures and memes help draw a lot of attention. In [my tips answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252234/456814), I recommended to only use these things when they help clarify what you're trying to say, and not to over-do it and abuse their usage.

**So in what cases would it not be appropriate to use big, eye-catching pictures and memes?** I can imagine scenarios where questions are littered with a bunch of answers that use really big pictures that don't really have anything to do with the answer itself, all just to draw attention to the answer.

Comment: I recall there being an edit war over an image macro in an answer, with one side arguing that it doesn't hurt the answer because it's non-essential, and the other arguing that since it's non-essential there was no need to include it. (There was also an edit war within that edit war on whether it should have been scaled down or left at full size.)

Comment: My favorite picture ever was a spam can I posted on a spam question. Both question and answer are long since deleted, but it still makes me chuckle.

Comment: Great [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252234/2587435) btw. Especially the part: _"Iz gonna edit ur face!"_ :-D

Comment: I think the real issue is memes are overused, unfunny jokes and should die a horrible death. But hey, who needs original humour?

Comment: I don't find cupcake's memes distracting from the answer, and readability is the key factor. Some may even find answers more readable or memorable with the aid of images, and unless it were to have the opposite effect on other users (doubtful), and that the answer is well composed and intelligible, I should think the rest of us are pretty at the mercy of the answerer's tastes.

Comment: Whatever. In pretty much every company I worked at (pretty much all top 10 in their respective software sphere) memes were flying back and forth as usual part of answers to technical questions. So any time I hear atrocity like "keeping it professional" regarding this, I read it instead "pretend to be suit for ... reasons".

Answer (score 14):

Personally I feel as if you have lodged a question to SO and you are an actual professional or serious programmer, you have asked the question because you legitimately need the help.

Unless the person submitting the question has started it on a humorous front (while asking a legitimate question) any meme's should not be used, and an image should only be used for descriptive purposes or to help understand the perspective of a question.

The last thing I would want is to be stressed out trying to solve a problem I have been working on for possibly days, and lodge a question to have someone start placing answers with meme's.

The emphasis on SO being for enthusiast/professionals programmers asking proper questions means there should be no need for images everywhere. Unless its useful, it should stay out in my opinion, theres plenty of discussion boards/forums to place these things.

Questions/Answers should be strict and nail solutions on the head, if not then there is no need for them at all.

If you think a question is not serious, then it should be -1 immediately, not played with and turned into a joke. There is way too much junk here.

Comment: You have a very strong argument with "keeping it professional". What about ***existing posts*** that already use memes, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17859891/456814)?. What about metaphors, like [the railroad branch metaphor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/456814)?

Comment: @Cupcake I would argue that there is a difference between a picture illustrating a point (as the railroad one does) or just a funny picture to get attention (and to be funny, obviously). While I think the first one is ok, the second one should be banned as the answer suggests.