# What to do with down-voted answer

Tags: discussion

From site guidelines ([vote-down page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)):

> *When should I vote down?
>   Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

I wrote an [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26506734/4022608), that while not perfect, ([first submission](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26506734/1)) was a valid algorithm.
Yes, I had a bug in my code, but the algorithm described is, I believe, an optimal one for the question posted.
Following that first post I edited it to improve it, but in the meantime, it was down-voted with no reason left.

As it stands now, I think it is a good answer, but that that down-vote pushed it to the bottom of the answer page, where, lets me honest, no-one really looks. This wan't helped by other (not so good) answers being posted and then deleted during the 'active' time of the question - i.e. when it was high in the "newest questions" list.

It remains, at this time, the only (remaining) answer that includes code to demonstrate an algorithm that solves the Question, the two answers with positive votes.

Now, ideally, it should be read and if it is good, voted up.  But how often are answers with a negative voting score actually looked at? I feel that it is more likely that it will be dismissed as an incorrect answer because of the score, without being read and understood (and then unlikely to be up-voted if it is good).

How should this be handled?

Just leave it?
I do realise that I could delete it and post it as a new answer, but this doesn't seem to be in-keeping with the ethos of the site, or particularly 'honest'

Comment: *"bottom of the answer page, where, lets me honest, no-one really looks."* umm...I look all the way through a post when looking for an answer...even the bottom

Comment: Posting a good answer is no guarantee of upvotes, there's not really much you can do about it. People are free to vote as they choose.

Comment: @codeMagic Ok, some people do. If there is a `-7`(or worse) answer there I guess it's like a morbid fascination in what dire answers there could be. I do think that most people would tend to read the top couple of answers, at least as far as the quality starts to go down, and ignore the rest.

Comment: @eddie_cat yeah, that's pretty much as I thought, I was mainly just wondering if there is a way to make it more likely to be read.  Maybe pretty pictures (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253211/how-do-you-use-pictures-and-memes-in-your-posts-appropriately)

Comment: I'm sure you are right in some cases, but my point is that there are *only 2* answers above yours, you also have an upvote (maybe meta effect), and it was only posted an hour ago. If you think it is useful, leave it. If not, delete it

Comment: @codeMagic there were more before. I think 3? were deleted from that question, and of course the other 0-vote question was above too.

Comment: tell you one thing @Baldrickk - you shouldn't have answered that poor question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your answer is down-voted you should do one of the following:

1. Fix it.

   Work out what's wrong. Is it a matter of style or substance? Address any issues, spelling mistakes etc. in the answer that might be causing people to down-vote it.

   Then it's up to other users to remove their original down-vote (if they return to the answer) or up-vote it if they think it's useful.
2. Delete it.

   If the post doesn't really add anything to the question then you might as well delete the answer.

Comment: or save yourself the headache and think twice before answering poor questions...